# Custom Django Admin Permissions for article Authors

Tags: django, web, django-models, permissions, django-admin

I'm building a website that will include articles. Article content will be stored in a database model. Example:

```
class article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    content = models.TextField()
    ...
```

I'm wanting to use the built-in admin app for adding new articles to the website. And I'm going to have a group called 'author' which will allow other people to log in to the admin section and add new content.

My issue is with the permissions. I want to give the 'author' group the permission to add, change, view and delete Articles. **But I want to restrict this to only articles that they have created.** Basically I don't want them to be able to update other author's posts.

Is there a way that I can give them custom permissions so that they only have the ability to change, view, and delete only their own posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) for that.

```
class ArticleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ArticleModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

Don't forget to register your ModelAdmin.

```
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Oh one other thing, the docs for get_queryset doesn't pass anything to super(). Just curious why you did here, or if that is just a mistake?

Comment: It's just the way I learned and I aways forget there's an easier way to do it haha. Don't forget to accept my answer, @Discoveringmypath. Good luck ^--^